# Sharing a folder with full access in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, file-sharing

I have the following situation:

- I need to share a folder in the root of drive C: on a Windows 7 machine.
- The share should provide read/write access for anybody on other machines on the local network.
- The Windows 7 machine is not part of a domain.
- I need to establish the share from code (command line tools).
- If at all possible, the code should work on any localized Windows 7 installation

To my understanding there are two types of permissions I have to deal with:

- **Share** permissions and
- **NTFS** permissions.

Both need to allow read/write access for the final solution to work.

Now, let's assume that the folder to be shared is named **C:\SharedFolder**. With elevated privileges I use command line tools to create the folder and then provide the share:

1. **MD C:\SharedFolder**
2. **NET SHARE ShareName=C:\SharedFolder /GRANT:Everyone,Full**
3. **icacls c:\SharedFolder /grant:r *S-1-1-0:F**

Step 1 creates the folder, step 2 creates the share with the right share-permissions, and 
step 3 adds the needed NTFS permissions, right? (note, that "**S-1-1-0**" is just the SID corresponding to "Everyone").

With these three steps I end up with the desired share, but when I connect to the share from another machine I only have read-only access! Why is that?

If I right-click on the shared folder on the Windows 7 machine I get this:

[image: Folder Properties Window]

**Note that the read-only check box is somewhat marked!**

I can easily solve the situation by clicking away the read-only mark (followed by click on "OK" or "Apply"), but how can I do this from code? And why is it at all necessary?

Also note, that the **NET SHARE** command  uses the term **"Everyone"** in its **/grant** switch. This is problematic, because in a German Windows 7 you should write "Jeder" instead of "Everyone", and in a Danish Windows the proper word would be "Alle".

This language problem is not an issue in the **icacls** command, because here I can use the corresponding SID instead (as shown). But how can I make the **NET SHARE** command work for any language too?